# how to call a number when you click it same as iphone phonebook?

Tags: iphone

I want to call a number when click that number(UIButton), just as in iphone phonebook?

Comment: Are you developing in objective-c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:1-234-567-8901"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telURL];
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSURL urlWithString:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3e1abc0c'

Comment: I have a button in my program, when pressed then I should call a number, but your code is giving above error

Comment: So yeah, I made a mistake when typing the method name from memory. Sorry about that. Would have been easy for you to have a look at the documentation to find the fix.

Comment: NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ]
      initWithString: @"tel://212-555-1234" ];, you didn't allocated it, and going to do, how, this is right way

Comment: '+[NSURL urlWithString:] has a typo error. It should be '+[NSURL URLWithString:

Comment: I have made it right, edit your answer, so that i may accept it properly

Answer (score 1):

Example:

`[[UIApplication application] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://99887766"]];`

Add it to the IBAction.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked
{
NSURL *telURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:urNumber"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telURL];

}
```